# Fire onclick event on the element created by javascript using element.innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, innerhtml

I'm creating a delete button by javascript using this code:

```
btnclick = '<button class="deleteMe">' + 'X' + '</button>';
output.innerHTML = "whatever" + btnclick;
```

How do I fire `onclick` function on this button? Right now I'm doing something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".deleteMe").on("click", function(){
    alert("clicked");
  });
});
```

And I'm not getting any alert message on button click.

Comment: This will helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suppose you have div as output,

you can simply append the button in your div and execute the function

```js
$('#output').append('whatever  <button class="deleteMe">x</button>');
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('body').on('click','.deleteMe',function(){ 
    alert('delete button clicked!!!');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thankyou, it helped me. But can you please tell me why did you use output.append and how did it make a difference And why was it not working while I was using output.innerHTML

Comment: .append is a Jquery function, I don't know what is output in your scenerio like (div, body, span)

and if you want to use innerHTML here use like 

`output[0].innerHTML`

Comment: if you understood, do upvote my answer

Comment: Jquery event listeners don't work on dynamic elements. You can use below syntax for adding event listener to a dynamic element :



$(document).ready(function(){ 
 $("body").on("click",".deleteMe", function(){
    alert("clicked");
  });
});

Comment: @AkKi the above code is working fine

Comment: @MumbaiWadala Yes, but we don't need extra variable (output in your case) with the syntax that I've provided above.

Comment: Thanks @AkKi somehow the above code is working fine and your code too seems good to me

Comment: so you can simply delete the variable after appending <button> to the div

Comment: and you do need extra variable to append the div

Comment: @MumbaiWadala what is the point of creating a variable and deleting it when the task can be accomplished without even creating an extra variable?

We all are developers and code optimisation should be our priority :)

Comment: thankyou @AkKi this works great as well.

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {  


$("#outputDiv").append("<button type = 'button' class = 'deleteMe'>Delete Me!</button>");  
  $(".deleteMe").on("click", function(){  
    alert("clicked");  
  });  
});

Comment: @AkKi updated my answer, have a look

Comment: This solution will not work. Please update your answer as follows :                                                                  $('#output').append('whatever  <button class="deleteMe">x</button>');
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('body').on('click', '.deleteMe',function(){ 
    alert('delete button clicked!!!');
  });
});

Comment: Upvote my comment if you find this working!